# Java Program Exercise code error

Tags: java

So the exercise is asking this
Write a Java class that declares named constants to represent the number of kilometers (`1.852`) and the number of miles (`1.150779`) in a nautical mile. Also, declare a variable to represent a number of nautical
miles and assign a value to it. Compute and display, with explanatory text, the value of kilometers and in miles. Assign a value to the nautical miles variable, accept it from the user as input. Output should be
user friendly.

This is the code I have come up with so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NauticalMilesKC
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner getKM = new Scanner(System.in); 
        double kilometer; 
        double nautical_mile; 

        System.out.print("Kilometer distance enter: "); 

        kilometer = getKM.nextDouble(); 

        nautical_mile = (kilometer * 540/1000); 

        System.out.println("Nautical mile equivalent is :"); 
        System.out.println(nautical_mile);
    }

}
```

I keep getting an error and it is not running

can anyone help me understand what Im doing wrong please
I will say that I'm a complete novice and this is my first java class

Comment: `"I keep getting an error"` -- what error? Please post the full error message so that we can fully understand your problem. Also, when posting code here, please strive to post **well-formatted** code, meaning code with proper indentations -- yours has none, making it hard to read, and you don't want to make your code harder to understand than it needs to be.

Comment: This code runs fine and gives the correct answer for me.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you are entering a non digit

Comment: Hovercraft, I apologize about my format, I just started java and Im still very wet behind the ears. The error that pops up after I compile it says

Comment: symbol: varible input and location: NauticalMilesKC

Comment: error reached while end of parsing

Comment: Please edit your post -- format your code appropriately, usually 4 spaces per block, and please post the complete error message with your question. Also, does your file name match that of the class?

Comment: Your instructions were to create named constants to represent the conversion ratios; you haven't done that.

Also, you aren't getting the correct value using "kilometer * 540/1000" since that is using integer math; if you enter 1 kilometer your answer will be zero.

Comment: @FredK: I don't think that's true since the kilometer variable is a double variable.

Comment: The program is ok (well he could close the stream), he is having compling problem!... I would first check the the file name is exactly NauticalMilesKC.java

Comment: What is your OS ? How do you compile, using an IDE or from a terminal ? Please edit your question to add these informations, someone should help you thanks to that =)

Comment: Futhermore we hope you don't have any other code in the NauticalMilesKC.java file with some missing brackets.

Comment: @FredK: I think HovercraftFullOfEels is right, expressions are evaluated from left to right in java, so the result should be a double.